# PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot access property started with '\\0'

Tags: php, wordpress, timber

So I'm using Timber v0.22.5. I have it currently running on my local and a dev environment right now. Everything is running great no issues. Both environments are running PHP 5.5.9.

I just migrated it to my production server which is running PHP 7.0. I am now getting the following error from Timber.

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot access property started with '\0'
>   in
>   /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/timber-library/lib/timber-core.php:67

I'm not sure what exactly else is different between the environments other than different versions of PHP. I cannot update to Timber v1 because well the guide seems to suggest not doing that because of some backwards compatibility issues.

I'm going to try installing PHP 5.5.9 and see if that does the trick but was wondering if anyone else was having this issue.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an issue with Timber 0.* and PHP 7. You should be able to fix it by replacing Timber/Core::import with the current version:

https://github.com/timber/timber/blob/master/lib/Core.php#L59-L75

Comment: Have not had time to test this but what ended up working for me was downgrading PHP to 5.6. I do want to take advantage of the performance improvements of PHP7 so when I get a chance I will give this a try. I'm going to mark this as the answer for now though.

Answer (score 0):

This will be happened if you use the latest version of "Better Search and Replace" plugin too. You should be able to fix by trimming the key:

https://github.com/deliciousbrains/better-search-replace/issues/71